# Is ufw loaded at boot before the login screen?

Tags: firewall, ufw

Assuming "ufw" is enabled, is it already loaded and working even before the login screen?

My concern is: I have a server at home which I usually switch on but do not login locally; if you look at the screen, you see the login screen. I may `ssh` to it away from home. Is "ufw" running while nobody is logged in after a reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `ufw` is a part of `multi-user.target` while a login manager like `lightdm` is a part of `graphical.target`.

```
$ systemctl cat ufw.service 
...
...
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you should know, all services under `multi-user.target` will be run before the `graphical.target`, because it's a dependency of `graphical.target`.

You can also use:

```
systemd-analyze plot > 1.html
```

then check `1.html` in your browser, you'll see that `ufw` has been enabled before your login manager.

[image]

The other option is to use:

```
systemctl list-dependencies
```

it'll help you find out which services in which order has been run.

[image]